# If desktop previously saved, then switch from *scratch* to last viewed file

Tags: emacs

Could someone please give me a hand switching to the last viewed file from the desktop save when opening Emacs, taking into consideration that my `*scratch*` buffer is also an existing file?

The `*scratch*` buffer always trumps the desktop save in terms of the initial buffer choice.

```
(setq initial-scratch-message nil)
;; (setq initial-buffer-choice "~/.0.data/.0.emacs/*scratch*")

(defun kill-default-scratch ()
    "Avoid having a buffer named `*scratch*<2>` when Emacs loads
    my preferred *scratch* file from a specified location -- however,
    yield to the last viewed file if it exists from desktop-save."
    (kill-buffer "*scratch*")
    (find-file "~/.0.data/.0.emacs/*scratch*") )

(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'kill-default-scratch)

(require 'saveplace)
(setq-default save-place t)
(setq save-place-file "~/.0.data/.0.emacs/.saved-places")

(desktop-save-mode 1)
(setq desktop-dirname           "~/.0.data/.0.emacs/"
    desktop-base-file-name      ".emacs.desktop"
    desktop-base-lock-name      ".lock"
    desktop-path                (list desktop-dirname)
    desktop-save                t
    desktop-files-not-to-save   "[*]bbdb[*]\\|[*]BBDB[*]\\|[*]TODO[*]" ;; "^$"  reload tramp paths
    desktop-load-locked-desktop nil )

(setq desktop-buffers-not-to-save
        (concat "\\("
                "^nn\\.a[0-9]+\\|\\.log\\|(ftp)\\|^tags\\|^TAGS"
                "\\|\\.emacs.*\\|\\.diary\\|\\.newsrc-dribble"
                "\\)$"))
    (add-to-list 'desktop-modes-not-to-save 'dired-mode)
    (add-to-list 'desktop-modes-not-to-save 'Info-mode)
    (add-to-list 'desktop-modes-not-to-save 'info-lookup-mode)
    (add-to-list 'desktop-modes-not-to-save 'fundamental-mode)
```

---

*EDIT*:  Based upon the answer provided by @juanleon, I decided to just let nature run its course and deal with it using the `emacs-startup-hook` (which loads subsequent to the `after-init-hook`).  The scratch buffer wants to trump `desktop.el`, so let it and then bury it.  To deal with the situation when there is no last viewed file saved by `desktop.el` (i.e., because they were all closed before exiting), I bury the `*Messages*` buffer (`if` it has focus) so the result is that the custom `*scratch*` buffer has focus again.  To remove the custom `*scratch*` file from the `desktop.el` save feature, I added `[*]scratch[*]` to the list of `desktop-files-not-to-save`.  I am using `auto-save-buffers-enhanced` to automatically save my custom `*scratch*` file (set to occur 1 second after every modification) and that utility lets me exclude user-defined file types with `(setq auto-save-buffers-enhanced-exclude-regexps . . .)`:  https://github.com/kentaro/auto-save-buffers-enhanced/blob/master/auto-save-buffers-enhanced.el  [NOTE:  The reference to `flet` therein would need to be changed to `cl-flet` if using a recent version of Emacs.]

```
(setq initial-scratch-message nil)
(setq initial-buffer-choice t)

(require 'auto-save-buffers-enhanced)
(auto-save-buffers-enhanced t)
(setq auto-save-buffers-enhanced-save-scratch-buffer-to-file-p 1)
(setq auto-save-buffers-enhanced-exclude-regexps '("^not-save-file" "\\.ignore$" "\\.txt" "[*]TODO[*]" "\\.yasnippet" "\\.tex" "\\user_pref" "\\.org_archive" "\\.org" "\\.ppet"))

(require 'saveplace)
(setq-default save-place t)
(setq save-place-file "~/.0.data/.0.emacs/.saved-places")

(desktop-save-mode 1) ;; uses the after-init-hook
(setq desktop-dirname           "~/.0.data/.0.emacs/"
    desktop-base-file-name      ".emacs.desktop"
    desktop-base-lock-name      ".lock"
    desktop-path                (list desktop-dirname)
    desktop-save                t
    desktop-files-not-to-save   "[*]scratch[*]\\|[*]bbdb[*]\\|[*]BBDB[*]\\|[*]TODO[*]" ;; "^$"  reload tramp paths
    desktop-load-locked-desktop nil )
(setq desktop-buffers-not-to-save
        (concat "\\("
                "^nn\\.a[0-9]+\\|\\.log\\|(ftp)\\|^tags\\|^TAGS"
                "\\|\\.emacs.*\\|\\.diary\\|\\.newsrc-dribble"
                "\\)$"))
    (add-to-list 'desktop-modes-not-to-save 'dired-mode)
    (add-to-list 'desktop-modes-not-to-save 'Info-mode)
    (add-to-list 'desktop-modes-not-to-save 'info-lookup-mode)
    (add-to-list 'desktop-modes-not-to-save 'fundamental-mode)

(defun custom-scratch-setup ()
"Avoid having a buffer named `*scratch*<2>` when Emacs loads
my preferred *scratch* file from a specified location -- however,
yield to the last viewed file if it exists from desktop-save."
    (kill-buffer "*scratch*")
    (message "The default `*scratch*` buffer has been killed.")
    (find-file "~/.0.data/.0.emacs/*scratch*")
    (message "Finished loading the custom `*scratch*` file.")
    (bury-buffer)
    (message "The buffer *scratch* has been buried.")
    (if (eq (current-buffer) 
            (get-buffer "*Messages*") )
        (progn    (bury-buffer)
        (message "The buffer *Messages* has been buried."))) )
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'custom-scratch-setup)
```

Comment: You have a `*scratch*` *file*? Any reason you don't just call it something different? The `*name*` convention is generally used for non-file buffers.

Comment: The last viewed file (stored by desktop save) was being trumped by my initial buffer choice or by my custom scratch file.  I sometimes keep important notes in my scratch buffer and I wanted a way to control the location where those notes are stored, with an auto-save feature every time modifications occur.  The issue of the last visited desktop save file being trumped occurred even if my custom note file had a different name -- e.g., `lawlist-notes.txt`.  The edit underneath my initial question contains a working solution for a current version of Emacs Trunk built `--with-ns` on an OSX box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess would be that `after-init-hook` runs after desktop has finished loading its stuff (desktop uses that hook)

So, the `find-file` will run at the end of everything, and `find-file` happens to "unbury" the buffer of a file, if already loaded.  You may add a `(bury-buffer)` at the end of your `kill-default-scratch` if you don't want it to taking over initial buffer choice, nor being the initial buffer choice.

Another option would be to swap the order the hooks in `after-init-hook` are run.  You can do that by playing with the moment desktop.el is "required" and/or using the arg APPEND of `add-hook`.  If your function is run before desktop's function, `(desktop-read)` will take precedence over your `find-file`

Comment: Thank you very much for your insight on what was occurring and for the suggestions -- greatly appreciated!  I've added a working solution as an edit underneath my initial question.